# Manually convert POST data to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way I can call ASP.Net's 'deserializer' manually.

Ill explain my situation. I have an abstract controller class and I want to add an abstract method. Each controller which inherits the abstract controller will override the method and in the body will create a specific model using the POST data.

Because each controller will use the data to create a different model I cant use the automatic model binder.

So I basically want to do something like

```
public abstract class abstractController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult abstract mustOverrideMethod();
    ...
}

public class specificController : abstractController
{
    public override JsonResult mustOverrideMethod()
    {
        var postData = Request.Form;
        // Convert postData into a specific Model
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a generic `AbstractController` class?:

```
public abstract class AbstractController<TModelType> : Controller
{
    public abstract JsonResult MustOverrideMethod(TModelType item);
    ...
}

public class SpecificController : AbstractController<MyModelType>
{
    [HttpPost]
    public override JsonResult MustOverrideMethod(MyModelType item)
    {
        // The ModelBinder should bind the form input to the item parameter in this method
    }
 }
```

Where the `MyModelType` is whatever class you're trying to post into the method?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just double-checked in a test project - can confirm this works for me. Good luck :)

Comment: @ConnorBishop - how did you get on with this solution? If you could mark the answer as accepted this will help future users having the same issue and it would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
        string age = Request.Form["age"];
        string gender = Request.Form["gender"];
```

remember `age` and `gender` are the name property of the input field.

Comment: I wondered if there was a way to automatically. My models have quite a few properties so I dont really want to set each one manually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you don't need to do that. If you're using MVC you can pass a parameter to you action method. Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ActionYouNeed(YourModel model)
{
   // Do what you need
}
```

Comment: I need to override the abstract method

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this.

```
public class specificController : abstractController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public override JsonResult mustOverrideMethod([FromBody]YourDataModel yourDataModel)
        {
            //You can now use yourDataModel variable here.
            youDataModel.DoAnythingYouLike etc...

        }
     }
```

Hope this helps..